# Bash do what i want not syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am trying to implement a but of logic to my script but I think i have missed something as it isn't triggering like it should.

My idea is simple I want the script to respond to a stream of text from another binary running in same terminal using a pipe.
The output looks like this

```
Received 835186
Received 835186
over and over
```

I was attempting to make a logic thingy to only pick up one of these rather that all of them.

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
TOGGLE="/toggle"
RUN=0
NUM2=1

lights (){
    if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
#below if line i suspect is not triggering but can't see why
        if [ $RUN  == "0" ]; then
            touch $TOGGLE
            #/l-off.py
            echo "off"
            ((RUN=RUN+1))
        else
            rm $TOGGLE
            #/l-on.py
            echo "on"
            ((RUN=RUN+1))
        fi
    fi
#    togggle_func
    }
timclear (){
    while [ $RUN  == "1" ];do
        sleep 2s
        RUN=0
    done &
}
    
togggle_func () {    
    if [ "$RUN" -ge "$NUM2" ]; then
        #RUN=0
        timclear
        #return
#    else
#        lights
    fi
    }
#lines below that i want to control how many times its triggered 

while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" == "Received 835186" ]] || [[ "$line" == "Received 818562" ]]; then
    #togggle_func
    lights
    dt=$(date '+%r %d/%m/%Y')
    echo "Light Switch Pressed at $dt"
    echo "run $RUN"
    echo "num $NUM2"
  fi
done
```

My question still related is how do I make this script run the pipe itself as i run it from the cli like this at the moment `/RFSniffer | /Rf_Test2.sh`

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOGGLE="/toggle"
RUN=0
NUM2=1
RFSNIFFERCMD="/RFSNIFFER"

lights (){
    if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
#below if line i suspect is not triggering but can't see why
        if [ $RUN  == "0" ]; then
            touch $TOGGLE
            #/l-off.py
            echo "off"
            ((RUN=RUN+1))
        else
            rm $TOGGLE
            #/l-on.py
            echo "on"
            ((RUN=RUN+1))
        fi
    fi
#    togggle_func
    }
timclear (){
    while [ $RUN  == "1" ];do
        sleep 2s
        RUN=0
    done &
}
    
togggle_func () {    
    if [ "$RUN" -ge "$NUM2" ]; then
        #RUN=0
        timclear
        #return
#    else
#        lights
    fi
    }
#lines below that i want to control how many times its triggered 

$RFSNIFFERCMD | while read line 
do
  if [[ "$line" == "Received 835186" ]] || [[ "$line" == "Received 818562" ]]; then
    #togggle_func
    lights
    dt=$(date '+%r %d/%m/%Y')
    echo "Light Switch Pressed at $dt"
    echo "run $RUN"
    echo "num $NUM2"
  fi
done
```

The key bit being the change to the while loop 11 lines from the bottom of the text, which is being fed the information.

If I might critique the script further, you appear to be relying on a file /toggle being created and deleted.  This seems to be a horrible way to track the state, and might be more efficiently served using a variable.  At minimum, make sure the TOGGLE file has a file extension and is written/read to and from RAMDISK (eg /dev/shm on Ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you @davidgo that worked. I'm not receiving any error messages anymore.

Comment: Now i Have a different problem. The logic is not working anymore it just seems to 'echo run 1
num 1' This script is intended as a light switch. If the user mistakenly presses the button for to long only one trigger is picked up not all of them. It also needs to be able to reset that var aftr say 60s.

Comment: Also you are correct i am using "toggle" as a way of to track the state but i just didn't know how to do that with a persistent var across reboots. Also how would i make it use a ramdisk on raspberrypi  2 armv6l Raspbian 10

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much ability to help further.  I don't think I've ever even played with a Pi (or Pi2) and I'm not a programmer by trade.  If https://geek-university.com/raspberry-pi/show-disk-space/ is accurate, then /run and /run/shm are ramdisk.  If persist across reboots is important you may well need to store stuff on disk, but I dont think that SD cards are designed for continuous writes so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

This is to hard to post as a comment, but I've had a play.  I wonder if my much simpler script below would fit what you are trying to do (and be easier to debug).  Rather then complex loops, I just keep a track of time in seconds to handle the debouncing.

```
#! /bin/bash

RFSNIFFERCMD="/RFSNIFFER"
DEBOUNCE=5


OLDTIME=$((`date +%s`-$DEBOUNCE))
TOGGLEFILE=/dev/shm/toggle.file

$RFSNIFFERCMD | while read line
do
    if [ "$line." == "Received 835186." ] || [ "$line."  == "Received 818562." ]
    then
        NOW=`date +%s`

        if [ $(($NOW - $OLDTIME)) -lt $DEBOUNCE ]
        then
            echo "Ignoring change at $NOW / $OLDTIME"
        elif [ -e $TOGGLEFILE ]
        then
            OLDTIME=$NOW
            rm $TOGGLEFILE
            echo "Turn On"
        else
            OLDTIME=$NOW
            touch $TOGGLEFILE
            echo "Turn Off"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Again thank you @davidgo.
It seems to work very well.
I have one question on line 7 why is OLDTIME subtracted from line 4 DEBOUNCE?

Comment: but nevertheless it works so thanks. the toggle var works nicely from program restarts on rpi. Not tested across reboots yet

Comment: I don't suppose you could help me with the rest of the code for my light switch? Its in python.

Comment: @Love-to-Make - I don't "do python" ! but it is probably a better language for coding this kind of thing in the a bash script.   DEBOUNCE is subtracted from the date for OLDTIME in line 4 so that the input is not ignored until the DEBOUNCE period has elapsed.  Actually thinking about it, I probably should have just initialised OLDTIME to 0